# Qt BLE QLowEnergyDescriptor characteristicChanged (Desktop OSes)

Tags: qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I thought I had found the answer to this problem here:

[Qt and Android characteristicChanged is not emitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377777/qt-and-android-characteristicchanged-is-not-emitted)

However, although it's the issue I have (I think) that solution doesn't help.

What I *can* do (please note this is not on Android, but on Linux, and needs to be on Windows too eventually if that is relevant):

- Scan for devices.
- Connect to device
- Have all its services listed
- List all characteristics within a service
- Read any characteristic within the services

However, what I *cannot* do is have a get a change of characteristic value to trigger a call to a slot.

I have this code:

```
  const QList<QLowEnergyCharacteristic> chars = service->characteristics();
    foreach (const QLowEnergyCharacteristic &ch, chars)
        {
        CharacteristicInfo *cInfo = new CharacteristicInfo(ch);
        m_characteristics.append(cInfo);
        fillHandlesTable(cInfo);
        if (cInfo->getHandle() == "0x15")
            {
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Going to attempt to look for changes to handle 15"); 
            QLowEnergyDescriptor notification = ch.descriptor(QBluetoothUuid( cInfo->getUuid()) );
            if (!notification.isValid())
                ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Oh no, that's not right");
            else
                {
                connect(service, SIGNAL(characteristicChanged(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)),
                        this, SLOT(newCharacteristicValue(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)));
                service->writeDescriptor(notification, QByteArray::fromHex("0100"));
                } 
            }
        }
```

I always get the line telling me Oh no, that's not right. I am not sure whether this line:

```
QLowEnergyDescriptor notification = ch.descriptor(QBluetoothUuid( cInfo->getUuid()) );
```

Is correct, especially the `QBluetoothUuid( cInfo->getUuid())` bit.

Or whether I have something else altogether wrong.

I should add that I did try exactly what was in the link I provided, but that also didn't work.

i.e. this:

```
QLowEnergyDescriptor notification = ch.descriptor(
    QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not in the Qt code, but that the characteristic was read, not read/notify.